# Joomla Component

Tags: joomla, components, installation

I just installed a new Joomla component but when I try to go to the component url, it tells me it cannot find it on the server. Please what could the problem be

Comment: What component is it?  Is it one you downloaded or one that you wrote?  Can you give more specifics so we have something to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a component link to menu? its often the step many people forget.

To do this just go to Main menu click add sign...and you should see in the list of types one or some relating to your component

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your cache or better, disable the cache.
2. Go to `Extensions -> Extensions Manager -> Discover` and you will see your component if it has not been installed correctly.
3. Go to your `phpMyAdmin` control panel, go to the table `_extensions` and see if your component is there (you will see the component id,name,url etc), otherwise you'll need to install the component again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Extensions -> Extensions Manager -> Seach the component that you installed.
2. If it is there uninstall it first.
3. And install it again.

I believe it will solve your problem.

Otherwise install the same component in the fresh installation of joomla. And go to extension table. Search the component and copy the row parameters and paste it into the db of your original joomla database extension table.

Answer (score 0):

What is Joomla version?

If it is J3.X then check your database tables and look for table #__extensions and look for your component if it there or not.

If not then try to uninstall and install it again and check the tables again,

Answer (score 0):

you'd tried use the url:
`youjoomlaurl/index.php?option=com_componentname`?
Remember that the file with the code of your component must have the same name of component `componentname.php`.
you also could try put the folder with the component directly in **joomla/components** folder and later try search your component click on the tab discover in extension manager.Don't forget the XML file.